# What is von Neumann bottleneck?

Tags: computer-architecture

According to [this Quora post](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-von-Neumann-bottleneck-and-how-can-it-be-circumvented),

> It refers to two things: A systems bottleneck, in that the bandwidth
>   between Central Processing Units and Random-Access Memory is much
>   lower than the speed at which a typical CPU can process data
>   internally. The 'intellectual bottleneck' in that programmers at the
>   time spent a lot of time thinking about code optimisation to stop
>   'lots of words' being pushed back and forth between CPU and RAM.

But according to my class lecture, it is the problem that "Generic implementation of single, common instruction and data hierarchy makes it impossible to access data and instructions at the same time. This is traditionally called von Neumann bottleneck."

Which one is correct?

Comment: Both.  One is a specific example of the other, and specific to what have come to be known as Von Neumann architectures (vs Harvard architectures with distinct code and data busses and address spaces).   In reality many modern systems are a hybrid architecture consisting of a Von Neumann type unified address space programming model and theoretical possibility, but a physical implementation optimized at least down to distinct address and data caches for primarily Harvard operation.

Comment: It's been my experience that when someone is talking about a *von Neumann bottleneck*, they are referring to your class lecture description, comparing with Harvard. The issue the difference between the CPU and memory (such as, for example, the difference in speed between a P II CPU and its backside bus to the L1 [and/or L2] cache (slower) or its frontside bus access to the chipset DRAM pipelines (much slower still) is ***not*** ascribed to that phrase. So the Quora post sounds (I didn't read it) from your description to be off the beam a bit.

Comment: Hence stacks inside the CPU, to hold lots of the function-call params.

Comment: Sorry, I meant distinct *code* and data caches.